# IIS7: Wildcard Mapping and Default Document

Tags: iis-7, wildcard

I am migrating an IIS6 website to IIS7 and I am hitting the well known problem of mixing a global ASP.NET handler while using default documents. See here for details:

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/david.wang/why-wildcard-application-mapping-can-disable-default-document-resolution)

Right now, in IIS7, I have the following modules configured, where "Everything" has a global.asax rewriting a lot of queries.

```
[... All default app modules ...]
<add name="StaticFile" path="*.*" verb="*" type="" modules="StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Read" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="" />
<add name="Everything" path="*" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="System.Web.UI.SimpleHandlerFactory" modules="ManagedPipelineHandler" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="integratedMode" />
```

With this configuration, default documents do not work because of "StaticFile" wildcard. My set of constraints is something like:

- Have all non-static requests handled by "Everything" global.asax for rewriting.
- Do not change global.asax code because it is complicated (we will tidy it up later).
- Have default documents for existing directories
- Do not handle static files in "Everything"
- Use IIS7 integrated mode

My current understanding is it cannot be done with this setup. So, one tradeof would be to *move* the global.asax rewriting code in an IHttpModule, registered after the static files. What's sad is it requires a separate assembly instead of editing the project directly. And I don't know how it will behave with Cassini.

What do you think? Is the IHttpModule the right approach? Could it be simpler?